# htaccess redirect variable img url to external img url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all images url to an external site using htaccess. The image url looks like this:

Source img url: /files/img04/uploaded/i4/18278023028506354/T1zRaGXqhaXXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg

Redirect to img url: http://img04.domaincdn.com/bao/uploaded/i4/18278023028506354/T1zRaGXqhaXXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg_230x230.jpg

img04: 04 is num variable, from 01 to 09.

i4: is same as img, just the prefix is "i", the num variable is same as img.

/18278023028506354/: this section will only use numbers, it's variable.

"T1zRaGXqha": this section will combine 0-9, a-z, A-Z, it's variable.

"XXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg": this section is not changing, all images has this section.

How should i write the htaccess rules to redirect it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, what have you tried?  Also, do you only pull one file size (230x230) from your cdn?

Comment: I have tried for: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/files/img([0-9]+)/uploaded/i([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)_!!0-item_pic.jpg$
RewriteRule ^$ http://img([0-9]+).domaincdn.com/bao/uploaded/i([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ ([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)_!!0-item_pic.jpg_230x230.jpg? [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: The above rules got 500 error, i have tried for many other rules to rewrite it, but not success. Any ideas for it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You were really close, your RewriteCond is missing a '_' before the `!!` and then you need to use `$1,$2,$3,..` to access the captured groups!

That being said, you don't need a RewriteCond, and you can just have the RewriteRule because it will handle the pattern matching, i.e. the RewriteCond is just repetitive.

```
RewriteRule ^files/img([0-9]+)/uploaded/i([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+\.jpg)  http://img$1.domaincdn.com/bao/uploaded/i$2/$3/$4.jpg_230x230.jpg? [R=301,NC,L]
```

I made one change, which was for the name of the actual jpg, since it is the last element, we can grab any number of characters that then end with `.jpg`